Cannot rebuild raid5 array with mdadm --assemble
I have somehow managed to corrupt my RAID 5 array. I am using Ubuntu 24.04, and my existing RAID5 array is on 3 x 240Gb SSDs, and my OS is on a 120Gb SSD. As far as I can tell the 3 raid discs are OK (I have checked using smartctl and badblocks - no errors reported). The Disks utility shows the disks as being members of a Raid.
If I issue the command sudo mdadm --assemble --force --run --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd I get the following response:
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Invalid argument

I don't understand the last line of the output - anyone?
Several times in the past when I have reinstalled my Ubuntu OS, all I have had to do to recover the Raid was to use mdadm --assemble (can't remember the full syntax I used) and that worked OK. So rather than reinstalling the OS I purge removed mdadm with apt, rebooted, updated and upgraded with apt, and reinstalled mdadm. As a result I no longer have outputs from cat /proc/mdstat, or a valid mdadm.conf file - sorry. Needless to say that didn't work. I tried using mdadm --build but it complained about not being able to build a level 5 raid - don't know why - anyone?
I don't want to go down the road of using mdadm --create because (I think) that will blow away the raid and create a new one. This would be disastrous for me, I need to get back my existing array even if it is in a degraded state so that I can backup the data and recreate it. Can anybody help save my sanity, please?
Regards, Stuart
The following is the output of mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcd]:
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ad660600:ca83c332:9dc8caf4:27e54f58
           Name : CAMELOT:0  (local to host CAMELOT)
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  9 13:13:07 2019
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 468613120 sectors (223.45 GiB 239.93 GB)
     Array Size : 468613120 KiB (446.90 GiB 479.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5356a893:aff50124:94357d6c:f651e98d

    Update Time : Mon Aug 19 10:52:38 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 56bfd60b - expected 56bfd60a
         Events : 5280

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ad660600:ca83c332:9dc8caf4:27e54f58
           Name : CAMELOT:0  (local to host CAMELOT)
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  9 13:13:07 2019
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 468613120 sectors (223.45 GiB 239.93 GB)
     Array Size : 468613120 KiB (446.90 GiB 479.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 00468b37:1615c86c:b303060b:1b1901b3

    Update Time : Mon Aug 19 10:52:38 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 7097a66 - expected 7097a65
         Events : 5280

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ad660600:ca83c332:9dc8caf4:27e54f58
           Name : CAMELOT:0  (local to host CAMELOT)
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  9 13:13:07 2019
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 468613120 sectors (223.45 GiB 239.93 GB)
     Array Size : 468613120 KiB (446.90 GiB 479.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b3576419:fa391d85:066ff51f:cb1644ad

    Update Time : Mon Aug 19 10:52:38 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 106a19fe - expected 106a19fd
         Events : 5280

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

The following is the end of the dmesg (not sure that you want all of it, but the following seems relevant):
[130713.548352] md: md0 stopped.
[130719.323276] md: md0 stopped.
[130719.328204]  sdb:
[130719.330236]  sdc:
[130719.331849]  sdd:
[130719.334706]  sdd:
[130719.362019] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 0
[130719.362029] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
[130719.362032] md/raid:md0: device sdd operational as raid disk 1
[130719.363639] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 3 out of 3 devices, algorithm 2
[130719.364554] md0: invalid bitmap file superblock: bad magic
[130719.364563] md0: failed to create bitmap (-22)
[130719.372586] md: md0 stopped.

The output from lsblk:
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0 268.4M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4650
loop3    7:3    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1439
loop4    7:4    0 269.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4757
loop5    7:5    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop6    7:6    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop7    7:7    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8    7:8    0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop9    7:9    0  10.4M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1147
loop10   7:10   0  10.5M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1173
loop11   7:11   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop12   7:12   0   476K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop13   7:13   0 149.6M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/497
loop14   7:14   0 149.6M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/507
loop15   7:15   0  74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1564
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   579M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  77.6G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   513M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   512M  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0  32.7G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdb      8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   0 223.6G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

The output from blkid:
/dev/sda6: UUID="aa7255a5-35a2-4994-84da-4c73cfecd06a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9c5d711c-06"


Attach the output of mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcd] and the dmesg messages corresponding to the attempt to assemble the array into the question, please. Also, lsblk and blkid are never hurt.

Hi Nikita, the question has been updated, as requested. Thanks for the response, and hopefully you will see something that helps. Regards, Stuart

[130719.364554] md0: invalid bitmap file superblock: bad magic is very suspicious. What happened, how did you get it into this state? Anyway, try using solution from this question, maybe, using --update=no-bitmap, and after it starts, re-add it again.

Many thanks Nikita, your advice to assemble with --update=no-bitmap did the trick. I have my RAID restored. Thanks again.

I suggest you to add your own answer into the "Your Answer" form below (and then accept it when it lets you), for both the question to not be left dangling "unanswered" here forever and for it to be marked answered so others to be able to solve should the face the same problem.
